# showdatepicker flutter text color showing white unselect year white how solve it

Tags: android, flutter

showDatePicker(
context: context,
//context of current state
initialDate: DateTime.now(),
firstDate: DateTime(2000),
//DateTime.now() - not to allow to choose before today.
lastDate: DateTime.now(),

```
)
```

color changing   showDatePicker(
context: context,
//context of current state
initialDate: DateTime.now(),
firstDate: DateTime(2000),
//DateTime.now() - not to allow to choose before today.
lastDate: DateTime.now(),

```
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget ?child) {
      return Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
          splashColor: Colors.black,
          textTheme: const TextTheme(
            subtitle1: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            button: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          hintColor: Colors.black,
          colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
              primary: Colors.blue,
              primaryVariant: Colors.black,
              secondaryVariant: Colors.black,
              onSecondary: Colors.black,
              onPrimary: Colors.white,
              surface: Colors.black,
              onSurface: Colors.black,
              secondary: Colors.black),
          dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: child ??Text(""),
      );
    }

)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you update it explaining more ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        //context of current state
        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: DateTime(2000),
        //DateTime.now() - not to allow to choose before today.
        lastDate: DateTime.now(),

    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget ?child) {
      return Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
          splashColor: Colors.black,
          textTheme: const TextTheme(
            subtitle1: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            button: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          hintColor: Colors.black,
          colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
              primary: Colors.blue,
              primaryVariant: Colors.black,
              secondaryVariant: Colors.black,
              onSecondary: Colors.black,
              onPrimary: Colors.white,
              surface: Colors.black,
              onSurface: Colors.black,
              secondary: Colors.black),
          dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: child ??Text(""),
      );
    }

)
```